# How to get the last ID got inserted into Database Table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a magazine management system. I've made archive for magazines using sql db table and php.
I want to show the latest magazine data on the home page by getting the last auto incremented id from the archive table from db. But how? I'm Using SQL, not PDO

Comment: are you using MYSQLI or PDO?

Comment: It would help if you could show some code.

Comment: You tried `MAX(id)`?

Comment: What is the problem? To find the row or display the magazine cover?

Comment: `$last_id = $conn->insert_id;` to get last insert id

Comment: I'm using Procedural sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

order by is easy way and if you only 1 record then use limit

```
select * from magazines order by id desc limit 1;
```

you can use mysql max function

```
select max(id) as ID from magazines;
```

and if you want to get last insert id in insert query then use this

```
 $last_id = $conn->insert_id; // mysqli

 $last_id = mysql_insert_id(); // mysql but remove from php 7

 $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId(); // pdo
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get what you want is probably the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM magazines
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But you might want to consider creating a date entered column to use instead of the auto increment ID.

Comment: '<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("rupok") or die(mysql_error());


$sql= "SELECT * FROM 'archive' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//echo arrays here

}
?>
'

Comment: I've wrote this code after you answered, it is showing this error,
**Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in**

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around the table name?

Comment: Should I have double quotes? I've tried, it shows a syntax error

Comment: _Don't_ put quotes around the table name.  Backticks if you must, but not quotes.

Comment: @tawsiftorabi - pls stop using `mysql_*`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: why? can you tell me the reason? i'm new in php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PDO, use PDO::lastInsertId.

If you're using Mysqli, use mysqli::$insert_id.

If you're still using Mysql:mysql_insert_id.

Answer (score 0):

The Query should be

```
SELECT max(ID) from magazine
```

This will return the maximum and the most recent id. You can then pass this query to desired PHP API